# How to calculate the confidence interval of a function of a combination of two linear models

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

We have two linear fits, one for each data-set (unfortunately they include weights but I'm willing to ignore that if there's a nice analytic solution to this). Data-set `d1` and `d2` are different in the sense that `x` is the same variable but includes different discrete points (so `x` in `d1` might be 100,120,500,... and `x` in `d2` might be 110,110,335,...), and their `y`'s are not the same. So in R jargon:

```
f1 <- lm(y~x,weights=w,data=d1)
f2 <- lm(y~x,weights=w,data=d2)
```

I then want to take the trend line of each of these fits and use it in the following equation:

```
z = 1 / exp( 0.02254*f1^2 / f2^2 )
```

I did that and plotted out this z, which is dandy. But! using the predict function in R, I managed to get the 95% confidence interval trend-lines of `f1` and `f2`, which makes a nice graph. I'd love to be able to calculate/plot the same confidence interval trend-lines for the `z` line.

The two ways I thought would work are:

1. to get the lower CI for `z` I take the lower CI for `f1` and the upper
   CI for `f2` and plug them into the `z` equation. To get the upper CI I
   do the opposite. I doubt this is correct.
2. I generate random `y` data for specific `x` data from the `f1` model (I'm
   not sure  how to do that) and then generate random `y` data for the
   same `x` data from the `f2` model. This way I have `y`'s for `d1` and `d2`
   that share the same `x` data. I then can plug those discrete `y`'s into
   the `z` equation and get my discrete `z` points. I then try to fit some
   model to that, though these discrete `z` points might not even follow a linear trend. this might be difficult or just silly.

So, this is my problem... Any brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 2):

(All credit goes to **Robert Shriver**, I'm just posting this for him!)
This is not an analytic solution, but I think that out of all the iterative solutions this ones' the nicest:

Take the mean regression parameters (intercept and slope) for both regressions (f1 and f2) along with the variance-covariance matrix of the intercept and slope parameters for each regression and plug them into a Multivariate normal distribution to simulate some new intercepts and slopes.

```
nn <- 100000
nx <- 100

bootf1 <- mvrnorm(nn, f1$coefficients, vcov(f1))
bootf2 <- mvrnorm(nn, f2$coefficients, vcov(f2))
```

This will be 10,000 random draws of the slope and intercept parameters for each regression. Use each one of these to determine the mean value of `z` across the range of `x` values you are interest in.

```
f1a <- bootf1[,2]
f1b <- bootf1[,1]
f2a <- bootf2[,2]
f2b <- bootf2[,1]

f1a <- rep(f1a, 1, nx)
f1b <- rep(f1b, 1, nx)
f2a <- rep(f2a, 1, nx)
f2b <- rep(f2b, 1, nx)

x  <- seq(-100, 1100, length=nx)
xs <- matrix(rep(x,nn), ncol=nx)

f1y <- f1b+f1a*xs
f2y <- f2b+f2a*xs

z = 1 / exp( 0.02254*f1y^2 / f2y^2 )
```

Then you can find the lower and upper CI of `z` as well as its mean by finding the .025 and .975 quantile of `z` at each `x` value.

```
setquantile <- function(x){
  r <- quantile(x, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
  return(r)
}

ci <- apply(z, 2, setquantile)
mu <- apply(z, 2, mean)

plot(x, mu, type="l")
lines(x, ci[1,])
lines(x, ci[2,])
```

That's it. Please let me know if you find something better. Hope this helped someone!